# Understand the support vector regression formulas

Tags: svm

So I am trying to get the SVR boundary conditions.

`w` normal vector of the plain

`x` feature vector

`b` constant plain offset

`e` epsillon (to define the height of the tube)

We say that the boundaries for our tube are:

`y >= w*x + b - e` # upper

`y <= w*x + b + e` # lower

Meaning that our y should be above the upper bound and below the lower bound.

But how can this be? Isn't the clue in SVR that we want all our data to be inside the tube? (I am ignoring the soft margin case here, but this has no influence on my question)

Maybe I don't understand what the correct meaning of `y` is here, since it's a regression case we probably don't use class labels here don't we? So what is `y` exactly? For me currently a value which when it is positive meaning that the feature vector is on the side of the plain where the `w` is pointing to.

Also when I would turn the definitions around saying that the upper is the lower and the lower is the upper it makes perfect sense, but I am pretty sure that the upper formula is the one for the upper bound.

EDIT:
When more thinking about it the formulas make sense IF `w` is pointing inside the tube. Because `y` will be positive for the upper bound IF `x` is on the side where `w` is pointing to. But can we safely assume that `w` is pointing inside the tube?